# Transforming each character into another consistent character

Tags: java, swift, algorithm, kotlin

For example, there is a data entry like this -> "ADdfe3783i, .- ^ #"

This is a unique value and I want to create a new unique value using it. I want to take this unique ID and generate a new ID where each character will always be the same character.

If it consisted of only letters and numbers, it was easy by specifying the equivalents, but any character can come.

I will use it in Kotlin, Java or Swift languages. It would be better with this, but it doesn't matter, I can interpret and transform, the important thing is logic.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you want by processing the above ID?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use String#replace() in Java?

Comment: @NomadMaker I can use but with what value will I replace it?

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire I shared an example as a comment to the answer of the friend below.

Comment: @enjektor0 I'm sorry, but I thought that you had already known what you wanted to replace the characters with. Why do you want to replace them at all?

Comment: @enjektor0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/64656185/2303865

Comment: Yeah, saying why you want to do it will help people answer you. If you really don't care what the result is, there's lots of things you could do - create a basic cipher, rotate the characters in the string, reverse it... if it needs to be unpredictable and irreversible (i.e. there are security implications) then that's a whole other question

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, I think you want to use input to create some mapping of characters like where `A = 1 , B = 2, ...`. And you want each input to have their own mapping.

If that is the case, you can try (you can omit encryption or SALT part) :

1. Create a SALT key for your project.
2. Append SALT key to input string.
3. Encrypt it using any algorithm you like.
4. Generate integer HASH of encrypted input.
5. Now you can perform substitution cipher techniques using this integer HASH, to make sure you get same mapping every time for same input string.

Comment: Actually I just want to create a new unique key from the unique key source. However, when I create a key from the same unique key again, I want it to generate the same value. We may not need encryption. Let's enrich it with examples like below.
------------
<Input: "A"
Output: "9">

<Input: "?"
Output: ".">

<INPUT: "BA"
OUTPUT: "49">

<INPUT: "9CAB."
OUTPOUT: "A19B?">

<INPUT: "A19B?"
OUTPUT: "9CAB."">

Comment: The value of a character entered in the input can be anything in the output. It is enough for a character to always become the same.

Comment: @enjektor0 Ok then you can omit encryption and SALT part, what you need is some value which can be used in substitution technique like HASH value. For example, if HASH = 1 (for sake of explanation only) , then you need to use this value in some way, here let's say you use it like input chars' ASCII + HASH mod (desired char range).